# How to get product attribute options into a custom module in Magento

Tags: php, magento, module, attributes

I'm working on an existing e-commerce site, where one of the custom attributes for a product is Designer, which is a dropdown list of names that have been added to the attribute under:

Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes

I'm building a custom module that will allow admins to create posts about designers, with additional info (bio, image etc), and ideally what I want is to restrict the admin user to creating posts only for designers that exist within that product attribute, by letting them set the name of the designer via a dropdown list of names populated by the values available to that product attribute.

I'm relatively new to using Magento, so I have no idea how to go about accessing those attribute values from within a custom module, and hoping someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will let you load a product attribute option array

```
    $arg_attribute          = 'YOUR ATTRIBUTE CODE';
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);
```